# Poner fila de Totales para cada columna en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, r-dplyr, dplyr

estoy trabajando con una tabla que es la siguiente :

```
 Especie `N Pies (ha)` `G ha` `VCC ha` `IAVC ha` `N Pies Tot` `G Tot` `VCC Tot` `IAVC Tot`
    <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1      44          39.9  0.653     1.20    0.0653        2091.    34.3      63.0       3.42
2      45          79.7  1.31      2.40    0.131         4181.    68.5     126.        6.85
3      46          39.9  0.653     1.20    0.0653        2091.    34.3      63.0       3.42
```

A esa tabla deseo agregarle una fila por debajo que diga `Total` para generar un informe en rmarkdown

El código que use para formar esa tabla es el siguiente :

```
tabla_sp_summarise= tabla_sp %>%
  group_by(Especie) %>%
  filter(Especie>0) %>%
  summarise("N Pies (ha)"= sum(N_pies_ha),
            "G ha" = sum(G_ha),
            "VCC ha" = sum(VCC_ha),
            "IAVC ha" = sum(IAVC_ha),
            "N Pies Tot"= sum(N_Pies_T),
            "G Tot" = sum(G_T),
            "VCC Tot" = sum(VCC_T),
            "IAVC Tot"= sum(IAVC_T))
```

He intentado con `colsums` pero me suma todo y saca la tabla original, hay alguna forma de agregar el total abajo en ese diseño de tabla que tengo?
Necesito esto:

```
    Especie `N Pies (ha)` `G ha` `VCC ha` `IAVC ha` `N Pies Tot` `G Tot` `VCC Tot` `IAVC Tot`
     <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1       44          39.9  0.653     1.20    0.0653        2091.    34.3      63.0       3.42
2       45          79.7  1.31      2.40    0.131         4181.    68.5     126.        6.85
3       46          39.9  0.653     1.20    0.0653        2091.    34.3      63.0       3.42
Total    -          159.47 2.61     4.80    0.26          8362.81  137.062  252.08      13.69
```

No me interesa sumar la "Especie", solo las otras variables

Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías calcular los totales y luego concatenarlos,

En primer lugar dejar la variable Especie como caracter

```
tabla_sp_summarise$Especie = as.character(tabla_sp_summarise$Especie)
```

En segundo lugar calcular los totales de solo las variables numericas:

```
Total = tabla_sp_summarise%>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  colSums()
```

Finalmente agregar esos totales a la tabla original:

```
tabla_totales = bind_rows(tabla_sp_summarise, Total)
```

Esto te concatenara los totales pero quedaras con un NA que puedes llamarlo Total para que tenga el formato que deseas, accediendo a ese elemento mediante:

```
tabla_totales[(dim(tabla_totales)[1]), 1] = "Total"
```

Comment: gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda, estoy comenzando con todo esto de las bases de datos , etc y varias cosas me quedan por seguir aprendiendo. Un saludo!

Comment: Por nada, para eso esta la comunidad, para ayudarnos entre todos, saludos !!

Answer (score 5):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, en cualquier caso es necesario crear primero el sumario (en este caso las sumatorias de las columnas nunéricas) y luego agregarlo como fila al final del data.frame con los datos.

La más simple es usando una libería que se llama `janitor` y tiene una función que es para eso:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

# Recreo los datos lo mejor que puedo. 

read.table(text = "Especie `NPies(ha)` `Gha` `VCCha` `IAVCha` `NPiesTot` `GTot` `VCCTot` `IAVCTot`
                   44          39.9  0.653     1.20    0.0653        2091.    34.3      63.0       3.42
                   45          79.7  1.31      2.40    0.131         4181.    68.5     126.        6.85
                   46          39.9  0.653     1.20    0.0653        2091.    34.3      63.0       3.42", 
           header = TRUE) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() -> datos #Le cambié los nombres

adorn_totals(datos)
 especie x_n_pies_ha x_gha x_vc_cha x_iav_cha x_n_pies_tot x_g_tot x_vcc_tot x_iavc_tot
      44        39.9 0.653      1.2    0.0653         2091    34.3        63       3.42
      45        79.7 1.310      2.4    0.1310         4181    68.5       126       6.85
      46        39.9 0.653      1.2    0.0653         2091    34.3        63       3.42
   Total       159.5 2.616      4.8    0.2616         8363   137.1       252      13.69
```

Si necesitas más control lo puedes hacer "a mano" `tidyverse`.

```
datos %>% 
#con el summarise se crea un un nuevo data.frame con una sola fila que tiene las sumatorias. 
#Los nombres de columna coinciden con el data.frame original, eso es importante para hacer la unión al final
  summarise(across(x_n_pies_ha:x_iavc_tot, sum)) %>% #across para hacerlo sobre un intervalo de columnas
  mutate(especie = "Total") %>%   #Aprovecho para marcar la etiqueta de total
  # Esta función une por filas dos data.frame, siempre que los nombres de columna coincidan 
  bind_rows(
    datos %>% mutate(especie = as.character(especie)), #Tengo que hacer character a especie para que se una con "total", de lo contrario tengo error porque numérico y caracter no se pegan
             .)
```

Queda así:

```
  especie x_n_pies_ha x_gha x_vc_cha x_iav_cha x_n_pies_tot x_g_tot x_vcc_tot x_iavc_tot
1      44        39.9 0.653      1.2    0.0653         2091    34.3        63       3.42
2      45        79.7 1.310      2.4    0.1310         4181    68.5       126       6.85
3      46        39.9 0.653      1.2    0.0653         2091    34.3        63       3.42
4   Total       159.5 2.616      4.8    0.2616         8363   137.1       252      13.69
```

Creo que si lo adaptas a los nombres de tu base de datos podría funcionar.

Es un poco extraño que esto que es básico y muy común en otros software como Excel sea relativamente complicado. Sin embargo es muy razonable, en R se considera buena práctica separar los datos, la lógica (el código) y los resultados (las sumatorias). En Excel, en cambio, es prácticamente imposible separarlo porque todo son celdas.

Comment: Una duda: cómo utilizas los valores del renglón "Total"? Cómo los llamas de la forma: my_df[my_df$total,]?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. De todos modos Total no es una fila, es un data.frame completo, por eso no uso [] o $ y luego pego los df.

Comment: No entendí tu respuesta. Me refiero a que si quieres sumar los totales, por ejemplo, cómo le harías? Con qué código? O si quieres utilizar el primer total (159.5) para hacer una operación con él (e.g. multiplicarlo por 2), con qué código lo harías?